# Cypress, How to get the count

Tags: cypress

I am trying to find the count of object in the webpage using Cypress and then validate that total number of records is correct. The data keeps changing so I cant hardcode it.

Is there a way to get the number?

Comment: Please tell us how would you identify the objects. By selector (e.g. class) or text?

Comment: Could you also post the html ?

Answer (score 9):

To get count of elements, you can use below code.

```
let countOfElements = 0;
cy.get(".element-selector").then($elements => {
    countOfElements = $elements.length;
  });
```

If you want to do verify the count of elements, you can do it like below.

```
// retry until we find 5 matching <.element-selector>
cy.get('.element-selector').should('have.length', 5)
```

You can check more about it in [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Length).